# How to control the relative sizes of graphics combined with Inset

Tags: plotting

I created a two grids like this

```
height = 125;
cb = MatrixPlot[
  Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 8}]
  , ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"
  , ImageSize -> {Automatic, 2*height}
  ]
```

[image]

```
p1 = MatrixPlot[
      Table[1, {i, 1, 1}, {j, 1, 2}]
      , Mesh -> True
      , ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]
      , ImageSize -> {Automatic, height}
      ]
```

[image]

If I combine the two with Inset, I get

```
Graphics[{First@cb, Inset[p1, {0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

What should I do if I want to cover the top-left two squares of the yellow/green grid with the red grid?

(I know I could redraw the larger grid with the color of some squares changed. But I want to know how to do it with Inset.)

---

Update, after trying to play with the parameters of Inset, I have found some appropriate parameters that works. But this takes a lot trials.

Is there a way to keep images with their "absolute" size when using Inset?

```
Manipulate[ Graphics[{First@cb,    Inset[p1, {x, y}, {Left, Bottom}, {Automatic, w}]},   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[cb]], {{x, -0.1}, -0.5,   0.5}, {{y, 0.8}, 0.0, 1.0}, {{w, 1.4}, 0.5, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Inset` can take up to five arguments. The three you don't use are ones the give control over the size and placement of the inset in the main graphics panel. Read the full documentation for `Inset` to find out how to the additional arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not an answer

I think that `Inset[]` is not what you need.

This is what is happening when one resizes a graphic with some `Inset[]` without the fourth argument :

[image]

If you need a layout that doesn't change when resizing, you can use the 4 arguments form, but I find it a way easier not to use `Inset[]`at all :.

Like this :

```
height = 125;
cb = MatrixPlot[
  Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 8}]
  , ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"
  , ImageSize -> {Automatic, 2*height}
  ];  

p1 = MatrixPlot[
  Table[1, {i, 1, 1}, {j, 1, 2}]
  , Mesh -> True
  , ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]
  , ImageSize -> {Automatic, height}
  ];

Graphics[{cb[[1, {1, 2}]], Translate[p1[[1, {1, 2}]], {0, 2}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit of the the last line of the code. I know what Translate does, but what is `cb[[1,{1,2}]]`?

Comment: `cb[[1,{1,2}]]` is equivalent to `cb[[1,1;;2]]` ,to  `Take[cb[[1]],2]` ... : it simply takes the first element at the first level, and then the 2 first elements at the second level. No subtelties. I confess I should have used a more common syntax.

Comment: @andr314 It seems that just cb[[1]] also does the job. What's the difference?